# Can you purchase the right to distribute GPLv3 code without disclosing source code?

Tags: licensing, gpl

WhatsApp uses the Signal protocol which is licensed under GPLv3. Am I right to assume that they should legally be required to publish their source code since they use the Signal protocol on binaries shipping to end user devices? Or is it common for library developers to offer/"sell" licenses to companies that wish to use GPLv3 code without having to disclose the full product source?

Comment: "Signal protocol which is licensed under GPLv3" <- no, it's not. A specific implementation of it might be. The actual document describing it might be, but the protocol itself is not as protocols cannot be copyrighted, so the GPL does not apply to them

Comment: I did not know that, thank you for the information on this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I write some program from scratch, I can choose to license as open source under e.g. GPLv3, and simultaneously license it for a stiff fee for use in closed source applications, no GPL strings attached. I could even get tired of it all and sell all rights. If my project gets third party contributions, I'll have to make sure the relevant rights are transferred to me. That isn't exactly popular among open source enthusiasts, for obvious reasons. This was the path taken by e.g. Qt (of KDE fame) and the business model behind MySQL. Not very successfully, I might add.

As comments note, what can be copyrighted is a specific work, like a program or a text describing a protocol. If somebody studies the protocol description and builds a program implementing it without including any of the description (i.e., no example code or such), the result is not bound at all by the description's copyright. Same with "clean room reimplementation": A team studies the program and writes up a specification, which is handed to another team that implements the specification. The result is not bound by the original's copyright, as it legally isn't derived from it.

Comment: MySQL not quite successful?! They were sold for like $2B... I guess it depends on your view on the matter.

Comment: That is a very insightful answer to the question

Comment: @AlexisWilke: It (the licensing strategy, not MySQL) "failed" because it did not prevent MariaDB from existing. My understanding of the situation is limited, but I believe MariaDB is technically superior to MySQL, and regardless it is not meaningfully controlled by Oracle. So the strategy of using a CLA to control what happens to the copyright can only go so far.

Comment: @Kevin  But The Contributor License Agreement (CLA) was not intended to prevent MariaDB from existing.  MariaDB existing was a result of releasing under the GPL.  The CLA's purpose was to allow closed source licensing agreements while still accepting community code contributions.  I.e. CLAs allow dual licensing.  They aren't intended to prevent anything other than claims that a closed source license is not in keeping with the GPL (or other licenses).

Comment: Re, implementing from spec, there may still be patents covering whatever is described (and AIUI the spec need not disclose whether there are such patents, I don't know whether the language "This specification does not grant rights under any patent that may exist regarding the described specification" is actually necessary). I've encountered a couple cases of this with MS' Open Specifications.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, as open source it is a flop. Several clones with no "sign over your rights" were soon created, like MariaDB, and MySQL got replaced.

Comment: @mdfst13: What's the point of having a proprietary MySQL when the open source equivalents are better? Sure, you could sell the code on a proprietary basis, but who's going to buy it?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, patents are a different kettle of fish, Relevant, sure; but the question is about copyright.

Comment: @mdfst13, the CLA couldn't stop anybody from forking the GPLed version, and open source contributors flocked to that version (less friction, for one). Thus MySQL as open source is moot. Same with Apache licenced OpenOffice + CLA, LibreOffice can take freely from it, not the other way around. RIP, OpenOffice.

Comment: @vonbrand  I am not at all convinced that the problem with MySQL has anything to do with the CLA.  Because MariaDB did not exist until after Oracle bought Sun.  But in order to work, the CLA had to exist from the beginning, before Sun bought MySQL.  I would also point out that MariaDB has a CLA, like MySQL.  If it's a failed business model, it should be failing for them as well.

Comment: @mdfst13, all GNU requires signing a CLA to contribute,in order for the FSF to have a standing in suing for violations of GPL.  The MySQL idea of selling commercial licenses while distributing under GPL creates a one-way street to the likes of a non-CLA MariaDB who don't want to do this.